# Download generate photo to file with link using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I Generate Photo on Website With JavaScript and use this code to download photo to my local computer but now I need to download it in file with link to use it.

```
const download = document.getElementById("download");
  download.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const canvas = document.getElementById("result");
    const canvasContent = canvas.toDataURL();
    const a = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.href = canvasContent;
    a.download = "photo.png";
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);
  });
```